# Enable button after closing a second window in python (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to re-enable a button in other window, the idea is that in my principal window press a button and start the second window, in this moment this button will be disable, and once the second window will be close, the button will need to be enable again.

I am trying to use `root.protocol("WN_DELET_WINDOW",self.on_closing)` but when I closed that window nothing happens. Actually I put a print sentence trying to identify if the program enter on this part, but the result is the same Nothing happens.

```
class SerialTkWindow():
def __init__(self,lock) -> None:
    lock.configure(state='disable')
    root    =Tk()
    root.geometry('300x100')
    root.title("Reset HU ?")
    root.resizable(0,0)

    
    #region Label
    welcomeLbl  = Label(root,text="Select COM Port",fg="black",bg=root["bg"],font="Helvetica 12")
    welcomeLbl.pack()
    #endregion

    root.protocol("WN_DELET_WINDOW",self.on_closing)

    root.mainloop()

def on_closing(self, lock):
        print("Regresamos")
        lock.configure(state=NORMAL)
```

lock is refered in `SerialTkWindow(self.sendCanBtn)` and self.sendCanBtn is refered in `self.sendCanBtn  = Button(frame3,text="Send CAN Msgs",command=self.CANMsgBtn)`

Comment: You have a typo - it's `"WM_DELETE_WINDOW"` and not `"WN_DELET_WINDOW"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `root.protocol("WN_DELETE_WINDOW",self.on_closing)`, you can call on_closing after the mainloop returns.

```py
from tkinter import *


class SerialTkWindow:
    def __init__(self, lock) -> None:
        self.lock = lock
        self.lock.configure(state='disable')
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x100')
        self.root.title("Reset HU ?")
        self.root.resizable(0, 0)

        # region Label
        self.welcomeLbl = Label(self.root, text="Select COM Port", fg="black", bg=root["bg"], font="Helvetica 12")
        self.welcomeLbl.pack()
        # endregion

    def on_closing(self):
        print("Regresamos")
        self.lock.configure(state=NORMAL)


root = Tk()


def open_serial_tk():
    win = SerialTkWindow(winbutton)
    while True:
        try:
            win.root.update()
            win.root.update_idletasks()
        except TclError:
            win.on_closing()
            break


winbutton = Button(root, text="open", command=open_serial_tk)

winbutton.pack()


root.mainloop()
```